# How severe do issues with a US grad school application have to be in order to cause degree revocation?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, application

I completed graduate school and found that I had made several mistakes in my application. Though none of them were fraudulent, my application was sloppy. I was intentionally vague and omitted some requested information.

For example, the school asked if I was enrolled anywhere else at the time of the application. I had signed up to take a summer course but did not mention this because I thought that enrollment meant degree seeking. I did not want to put it on my application, because I had an issue with panic attacks during this course and I was worried I would drop it under the increased pressure of having the school be aware of this.

Most of my other mistakes are of this caliber such as embellishment by choosing careful wording and omitting dates to be ambiguous and vague. This was because I did not have a great work history and did not have a job at the time. While this is not lying, I still feel bad about it.

I do not have a formal academic integrity record with the school, but I was warned for using resources that I should not have. I suffer from an anxiety disorder, but I learned to overcome it. Unfortunately, my character was not perfect during this time. I grew a lot over the program and if I were to reapply, I would write a different application. I regret what I did, but I cannot change it.

Is this something to be concerned about? It has been bothering me.

Comment: I suppose, it is an open-ended question

Comment: I would say: mistakes in your application will not cause revocation of your degree.  Fraudulent application may, at worst, cause you to be kicked out of the graduate program; but not after you receive the degree.

Comment: That's good to know, I won't bother them then. If there is an issue, I'm sure they will contact me and worst case, I already have the skills.

Comment: You've graduated without actively defrauding anyone. Everyone has moved on. I would suggest you do the same.

Comment: Yes. My university has only revoked degrees from people who commit serious fraud obtaining the degree, so I am fine. I don't like that my app was poor, but I cannot bother people about it and not be a productive member of society myself.